# Change some data and resolve in CPLEX with flow control

Tags: cplex

I failed to change the value of due_time in each iteration. How can I change my code?

```
ct9: // due time 
forall(k in orders, j in orders_nodes[k]:j in k.dest) 
    arrival_time[k][j]<=due_time;



main {
    thisOplModel.generate();
    var new_due = 25;
    
    while( new_due <50)
    {  ...

    new_due ++;
    thisOplModel.ct9.UB = new_due;
    }
 }
```

CPLEX told me the UB of ct9 is undefined. Is the due_time in the right side of ct9 an UB?

I also tried `thisOplModel.due_time ++;` but failed. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

```
 // due time 
 forall(k in orders, j in orders_nodes[k]) 
     ct9: if (j in k.dest) arrival_time[k][j]<=due_time;
```

plus instead of

```
thisOplModel.ct9.UB
```

you should index ct9

```
thisOplModel.ct9[k][j].UB = new_due;
```

small example from [Flow control and incremental changes](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooflowcontrolincremental.mod) in [Making Optimization Simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/)

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}

execute
{
writeln("nbBus40 = ",nbBus40);
writeln("nbBus30 = ",nbBus30);
}

main
{
thisOplModel.generate();

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

//now 350 kids instead of 300
writeln("now 350 kids instead of 300");
    
thisOplModel.ctKids.LB=350;

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();


// no more than 4 buses 40 seats
writeln("no more than 4 buses 40 seats");

thisOplModel.nbBus40.UB=4;

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

// change the objective so that cost for 40 seats is 450
// and remove the limit on the number of buses 40 seats

writeln("change the objective so that cost for 40 seats is 450");
writeln("and remove the limit on the number of buses 40 seats");    

thisOplModel.nbBus40.UB=1000;
cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus40,450);
cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus30,400);

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

 


}
```

which gives

```
nbBus40 = 6
nbBus30 = 2
now 350 kids instead of 300
nbBus40 = 8
nbBus30 = 1
no more than 4 buses 40 seats
nbBus40 = 2
nbBus30 = 9
change the objective so that cost for 40 seats is 450
and remove the limit on the number of buses 40 seats
nbBus40 = 8
nbBus30 = 1
```

and for your loop see

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;

range r=1..4;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40[i in r][j in r];
dvar int+ nbBus30[i in r][j in r];
 
minimize
 sum(i,j in r)(costBus40*nbBus40[i][j]  +nbBus30[i][j]*costBus30);
 
subject to
{
 forall(i,j in r)ctKids: if (i!=j) 40*nbBus40[i][j]+nbBus30[i][j]*30>=nbKids;
}

execute
{
writeln("nbBus40 = ",nbBus40);
writeln("nbBus30 = ",nbBus30);
}

main
{
thisOplModel.generate();

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();

//now 350 kids instead of 300
writeln("now 350 kids instead of 300");
    
for(i in thisOplModel.r) for(j in thisOplModel.r) if (i!=j) thisOplModel.ctKids[i][j].LB=350;

cplex.solve();
thisOplModel.postProcess();






 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your sharing. I still cannot change the upbound of ct9 and CPLEX told me the index is variable. Index k and j is given in data document. Do you know why?

Or I think we can change the due time of each order instead of changing the upbound of ct9. Then I wrote these codes. I used to output the due time of the first order. yes! It changed! But the objective didn't changed. The objective should be smaller when rising the due time, and it was smaller when I change the ride side of ct9 equal and less to 45. like:

```
ct9:// due time 
forall(k in orders, j in k.dest) 
arrival_time[k][j]<=45;
```

Do you know how to correct these codes?

main {

```
    var ofile = new IloOplOutputFile("due time and threshold.txt");
    var new_due = 40;
    var due_max = 45; 

    writeln("due time changes from  "+ new_due+" to  "+due_max);

    
    while( new_due <= due_max )
    {           
        ofile.writeln("For due time = "+new_due);
        ofile.writeln("**************************************");
        
        thisOplModel.generate();
        cplex.solve()
        thisOplModel.postProcess();
        
        
        if (cplex.getCplexStatus())
        {
            for (var k in thisOplModel.orders)
            {
                                                    
               ofile.writeln(" *  for order "+ k.no+"    "+k.volume);     
                for( var s in thisOplModel.services)
                    {                   
                    for( var a in thisOplModel.orders_arcs[k])
                        { if (thisOplModel.x[k][a][s]>0 && a==s.a)
                            { 
                            ofile.writeln(" via arc  "+ a +" by  "+ s.keynumb);
            
                             }  
                        }
                     }                                                                       
                 
                 ofile.writeln("    ");     
                 ofile.writeln("    ");   
             }   
             writeln("objective is "+thisOplModel.WH_income+"    ");    
             writeln("    ");     
                     
         }
         else
        { 
            writeln("No solution"); 
            writeln(cplex.getCplexStatus());
            break;
        }
        
        new_due ++;
        
        for (var k=1; k<=thisOplModel.N_order;k++)
        {   
            temp_order = Opl.item(thisOplModel.orders,k-1); 
            temp_order.due_time = new_due;
            if (k==1)
            {writeln("new due time for next iteration is "+temp_order.due_time);
             writeln("    "); }
        }   
        
    
    }
```

Comment: Instead of  j in k.dest you should write a range that does not depend on k and use an if after that as in "forall(i,j in r)ctKids: if (i!=j) 40*nbBus40[i][j]+nbBus30[i][j]*30>=nbKids;"